# How to remove ear wax and other dirt that went into my pods without opening them?

Tags: cleaning, technology, headphones, repair

I have these pods from Oppo for almost 5 months now and they are causing problems. Basically, after I use them for some time the audio from the left starts decreasing till I can barely hear it. But if I press it deeper into my ear or tap it hard I can hear it better for a moment. I think it could be wax and all that's got in there, and I want to know how to remove, it as going out and getting it opened for a check is too risky because of Covid-19.

Answer (score 1):

**Likely never recommended by the Manufacturer but I find it works:**

I’ve had success with rubbing alcohol as it is a polar solvent that can really loosen up wax. I use a cue tip and make sure not to drench them. Then I immediately blow dry on very LOW heat or no heat for at most 5 seconds. Then leave them overnight to dry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Vacuum-clean it.
2. Use this sort of cleaning slime.  You can [buy it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GW9TJ3G) or [DIY](https://www.cnet.com/home/smart-home/how-to-make-cleaning-slime-for-electronics/)

Answer (score 0):

Born and Bred in Cairns and I used to get a Tropical Ear every summer when I was younger and my Nanna put 2 drops of warm cooking oil

Comment: Hi Bernice Sexy Joinbee, Welcome to Lifehacks. Be sure to visit [Tour] and [Help] to find out more about our site. Are you sure you want to suggest putting warm cooking oil into earpods to remove wax and debris? I don't think so.